# Yellow spots on Dracaena Reflexa

Tags: dracaena

I have some yellow spots on my Dracaena, see the first picture. The plant is getting a lot of light and looks really happy, exept these spots, there is also a little bit of sticky substance on the underside of the leaves near the stem, but I don’t see any scale. What is wrong? [image][image]

Comment: How often is this plant watered? Have you ever fertilized it? how long have you had it?

Comment: It  was watered maybe twice a week when I got it, but then I changed it to maye once per two weeks, it is very humid where I live (not below 50, normally around 60percent). I also had it placed several meters from the windows, and didn’t fertilize it in the beginning since I got it in March this year.

Answer (score 1):

The sticky spots are a characteristic of the species and are not a problem

The yellowing of the leaves is sometimes seen on older plants where the soil can no longer buffer the chlorine or chloramine commonly added to tap water.  It can also be seen in plants under stress from overwatering

In both cases the initial stress is a fertile ground for virus fungus bacteria to take hold in the older leaves. Their by products kill cell tissue and cause the yellowing and bumps

I recommend

- Using filtered water
- move to higher light
- consider watering less
- remove yellowing  leaves

Most plants can out grow this problem if caught early.

Comment: Aren't those eggs I can see in the final picture, central stem?

Comment: Sap, "As it matures (at around 5 feet tall) your plant may begin to ooze a sticky sap" http://www.botanical-journeys-plant-guides.com/dracaena-marginata.html